# How to send a checkbox group via ajax in jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to send a group of checkboxes (with some other data as well) via ajax in jquery.

What I've done so far is:

```
var arr = $('#somediv input[type="checkbox"]:checked').val() || [];
$.post("/somephpfile.php", {str: str, arr: arr}, function(data) {...
```

But my problem is that the arr is never an array. What I need is to send it as ?str=data&arr=foo&arr=bar

I guess this is a very simple question, but since I am very new to jquery I'll ask the pros.
How should I do it?

Thank you.

---

**My bad, it was the php**

Comment: If it were an array I realise I probably need to make it a string anyway by formatting it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be looking for [.serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

A more generic solution would be to have a form with all the parameters and then serialize it.

Answer (score 4):

Ran into a similar problem and after much pulling of hair fixed it with SerializeArray

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="userList[]" value="<?=$userID;?>" /><?= $userName;?>
```

**jQuery**

```
var userList = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').serializeArray();
```

**PHP**

```
$userList = $_POST['userList'];
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($userList);$i++)
{
    $userID = $userList[$i][value] ;
    //Insert $userID to DB
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
        var selectedItems = [];
        $('#somediv input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
                selectedItems .push($(this).val());
        });

        var postData = { "str": str, "arr": selectedItems };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/somephpfile.php",
            data: postData,
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
                ...
            }
        });
```

PS I'm assuming you know about serialize and it's not right for your scenario. Definitely check that out first (although it will serialize the whole element). This means if your checkboxes don't have the same NAME attribute or you need to control the variable name they are passed in as you can use my suggestion to do it manually.

Comment: you can serialize() individual inputs/selects/textareas as long as they are in the jQuery collection.  For most just doing the form is easiest.

Comment: I was sloppy in my explanaition there. Edited to clarify what I meant.

Comment: Serialize fixed my problem, but now I only need to figure out how to send it with the string. But I think I know how

Answer (score 1):

Use `serialize()`, as `val()` just takes the value of the first element in the jquery collection.
http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

```
var postdata = $('#somediv input[type="checkbox"]').serialize();
$.post("/somephpfile.php", postdata, function(data) {...
```

Comment: If I also want to send a string "str" as in my example, how would I do that? it would be nice using { str: str, arr: arr } but that will make it wierd -> &arr=serialized data

Comment: then instead of seralize, do serializeArray().  Then you can do postdata.push({name: str, value:str});  http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/