# Can't processing values in HTML PHP Form correctly

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

This is seriously doing my head in and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong but I've got an online php form with checkboxes but when I leave the checkboxes empty and submit the form, receive the email ... the very first checkbox option shows up (almost like I've ticked / chosen that option) and the second checkbox option doesn't show up (which seems correct cos I didn't tick it)

Then when I tick both checkboxes, the same results come back as above.

I want it to behave normally like:
1) only the ticked checkbox options must show up
2) If I don't tick any checkboxes, they must not show up in the form email submission.

**My PHP Form Processor:**

```
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

if(!$_POST) exit;

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");



$address = "email@example.com";
$bcc = "email@example.com";

    $twitter_active     = 0;
    $twitter_user       = "";
    $consumer_key       = "";
    $consumer_secret    = "";
    $token              = "";
    $secret             = "";

$title = $_POST['title'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$idnum = $_POST['idnum'];
$birth = $_POST['birth'];
$married = $_POST['married'];
$officephone = $_POST['officephone'];
$cellphone = $_POST['cellphone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$position = $_POST['position'];
$addressline1 = $_POST['addressline1'];
$addressline2 = $_POST['addressline2'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$postalcode  = $_POST['postalcode'];
$bookingdate = $_POST['bookingdate'];
$estimate = $_POST['estimate'];
$currentpackages = $_POST['currentpackages'];

$treatment01 = $_POST['treatment01'];

$specialrequests = $_POST['specialrequests'];

if (isset($_POST['verify'])) :
    $posted_verify   = $_POST['verify'];
    $posted_verify   = md5($posted_verify);
else :
    $posted_verify = '';
endif;

// Important Variables
$session_verify = $_SESSION['verify'];

if (empty($session_verify)) $session_verify = $_COOKIE['verify'];

$error = '';

    if(trim($title) == '') {
        $error .= '<li>Your title is required.</li>';
    }

    if(trim($firstname) == '') {
        $error .= '<li>Your first name is required.</li>';
    }

    if(trim($lastname) == '') {
        $error .= '<li>Your last name is required.</li>';
    }

    if(trim($idnum) == '') {
        $error .= '<li>Your ID Number is required.</li>';
    }

    if(trim($birth) == '') {
        $error .= '<li>Your Date of Birth is required.</li>';
    }

    if(trim($cellphone) == '') {
        $error .= '<li>Your cell number is required.</li>';
    } elseif(!is_numeric($cellphone)) {
        $error .= '<li>Your cell number can only contain digits (numbers and no 
 spaces).</li>';
    }

    if(trim($email) == '') {
        $error .= '<li>Your e-mail address is required.</li>';
    } elseif(!isEmail($email)) {
        $error .= '<li>You have entered an invalid e-mail address.</li>';
    }

    if(trim($bookingdate) == '') {
        $error .= '<li>You must enter your booking date.</li>';
    }

    if(trim($estimate) == '') {
        $error .= '<li>You must enter your estimate time of arrival.</li>';
    }

    if(trim($currentpackages) == '') {
        $error .= '<li>You must enter a package.</li>';
    }

    if($session_verify != $posted_verify) {
        $error .= '<li>The verification code you entered is incorrect.</li>';
    }

    if($error != '') {
        echo '<div class="error_title">Attention! Please correct the errors below and 
try again.';
        echo '<ul class="error_messages">' . $error . '</ul>';
        echo '<div class="closebox"><img src="icon-close.png" /></div>';
        echo '</div>';

    } else {

    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { $comments = stripslashes($comments); }


     $e_subject = 'Check in Details from example.com';


     $msg = '<html><body>
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<!--DWLayoutTable-->
<tr>
<td width="600" height="88" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" 
cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <!--DWLayoutTable-->
  <tr>
    <td width="600" height="88" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#F0F5FB"><span 
style="font-family:Georgia, \'Times New Roman\', Times, serif; font-size: 24px; 
font-style:italic; color:#0099CC; line-height:48px; "><strong>Check in 
Details</strong> from:</span><br />
      <span style="background-color:#FFF; padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px; 
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#818181"><a 
style="color:#818181; text-decoration:none;" href="http://www.example.com" 
target="_blank">www.example.com</a></span></td>
</tr>
</table>    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="30">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="790" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" 
cellspacing="0">
  <!--DWLayoutTable-->

  <tr>
    <td width="225" height="570" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" 
cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <!--DWLayoutTable-->
      <tr>
        <td width="225" height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, 
Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333333; font-weight:bold; padding-  
left:15px;">Title:</span></td>
          </tr>
      <tr bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
        <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333333; font-weight:bold; padding-left:15px;">First 
Name:</span></td>
          </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 

sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333333; font-weight:bold; padding-left:15px;">Last 
Name:</span></td>
          </tr>
      <tr bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
        <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333333; font-weight:bold; padding-left:15px;">ID 
Number:</span></td>
          </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333333; font-weight:bold; padding-left:15px;">Date 
of Birth:</span></td>
          </tr>
      <tr bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
        <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333333; font-weight:bold; padding-left:15px;">If 
Married, Date</span></td>
          </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333333; font-weight:bold; padding-
left:15px;">Office Phone</span></td>
          </tr>
      <tr bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
        <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333333; font-weight:bold; padding-left:15px;">Cell  
Phone</span></td>
          </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333333; font-weight:bold; padding-left:15px;">Email:
</span></td>
          </tr>
      <tr bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
        <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333333; font-weight:bold; padding-
 left:15px;">Company:</span></td>
          </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333333; font-weight:bold; padding-
left:15px;">Position:</span></td>
          </tr>
      <tr bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
        <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333333; font-weight:bold; padding-
left:15px;">Address 
Line 1:</span></td>
          </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333333; font-weight:bold; padding-
left:15px;">Address Line 2:</span></td>
          </tr>
      <tr bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
        <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333333; font-weight:bold; padding-left:15px;">City:
</span></td>
          </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333333; font-weight:bold; padding-
left:15px;">Postal Code:</span></td>
          </tr>
      <tr bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
        <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333333; font-weight:bold; padding-
left:15px;">Booking 
Date:</span></td>
          </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333333; font-weight:bold; padding-
left:15px;">Estimate 
Time of Arrival:</span></td>
          </tr>
      <tr bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
        <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333333; font-weight:bold; padding-
left:15px;">Current 
Packages:</span></td>
          </tr>
      <tr bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
        <td height="30" valign="middle"><!--DWLayoutEmptyCell-->&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>









      </table></td>
      <td width="375" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" 
cellspacing="0">
          <!--DWLayoutTable-->
          <tr>
            <td width="375" height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-
family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px;">'.$_POST['title'].'</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
            <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px;">'.$_POST['firstname'].'</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px;">'.$_POST['lastname'].'</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
            <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px;">'.$_POST['idnum'].'</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px;">'.$_POST['birth'].'</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
            <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px;">'.$_POST['married'].'</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px;">'.$_POST['officephone'].'</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
            <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px;">'.$_POST['cellphone'].'</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px;">'.$_POST['email'].'</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
            <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px;">'.$_POST['company'].'</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px;">'.$_POST['position'].'</span></td>

          </tr>
          <tr bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
            <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px;">'.$_POST['addressline1'].'</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px;">'.$_POST['addressline2'].'</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
            <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px;">'.$_POST['city'].'</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px;">'.$_POST['postalcode'].'</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
            <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px;">'.$_POST['bookingdate'].'</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px;">'.$_POST['estimate'].'</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
            <td height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px;">'.$_POST['currentpackages'].'</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
            <td height="30" valign="middle"><!--DWLayoutEmptyCell-->&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>










      </table></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="119" colspan="2" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" 
cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <!--DWLayoutTable-->
      <tr>
        <td height="19" colspan="2" valign="top"><!--DWLayoutEmptyCell-->&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="225" height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, 
Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333333; font-weight:bold; padding-
left:15px;">Treatments Category 1:</span></td>
            <td width="375" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px;">'.$_POST['treatment01'].'</span></td>
          </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="20" colspan="2" valign="top"><!--DWLayoutEmptyCell-->&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>













      </table></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="71" colspan="2" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" 
cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <!--DWLayoutTable-->
      <tr>
        <td height="19" colspan="2" valign="top"><!--DWLayoutEmptyCell-->&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="225" height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, 
Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333333; font-weight:bold; padding-
left:15px;">Treatments Category 2:</span></td>
            <td width="375" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px;"></span></td>
          </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="20" colspan="2" valign="top"><!--DWLayoutEmptyCell-->&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>













      </table></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="30" colspan="2" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" 
cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <!--DWLayoutTable-->
      <tr>
        <td width="225" height="30" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, 
Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333333; font-weight:bold; padding-
left:15px;">Special Requests</span></td>
            <td width="375" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px;">'.$_POST['specialrequests'].'</span></td>
          </tr>

      </table></td>
    </tr>




</table></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="27" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" 
 cellspacing="0">
    <!--DWLayoutTable-->
    <tr>
      <td width="600" height="27">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="54" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" 
cellspacing="0">
    <!--DWLayoutTable-->
    <tr>
      <td width="600" height="54" align="center" valign="middle" 
bgcolor="#F0F5FB"><span style="font-family:Georgia, \'Times New Roman\', Times, serif; 
font-size:12px; font-style:italic; text-decoration:underline;"><a 
style="color:#626262;" href="http://www.example.com/" target="_blank">Click here to 
see your website</a></span>   
</td>
    </tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table>
     </body></html>';

    if($twitter_active == 1) {

        $twitter_msg = $name . " - " . $comments . ". You can contact " . $name . " 
via email, " . $email ." or via phone " . $phone . ".";
        twittermessage($twitter_user, $twitter_msg, $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, 
$token, $secret);

    }

    $msg = wordwrap( $msg, 70 );

    $headers = "From: $email\r\nBCC:{$bcc}\r\n" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit'. "\n\r\n" . PHP_EOL;

    if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {


     echo "<div class='greenbox' id='success_page'>";
     echo "<strong>Email Sent Successfully.</strong>";
     echo "<div class='closebox'><img src='icon-close.png' /></div>";
     echo "</div>";


     } else {

     echo 'ERROR!'; // Dont Edit.

     }

}

function twittermessage($user, $message, $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $token, 
$secret) { // Twitter Direct Message function, do not edit.

require_once('twitter/EpiCurl.php');
require_once('twitter/EpiOAuth.php');
require_once('twitter/EpiTwitter.php');

$Twitter = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
$Twitter->setToken($token, $secret);

$direct_message = $Twitter->post_direct_messagesNew( array('user' => $user, 'text' =>  
$message) );
$tweet_info = $direct_message->responseText;

}

function isEmail($email) { // Email address verification, do not edit.

return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*
[[:alnum:]])\.)+  
  (ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|s
```

csd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt
    |tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9]
    [0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]).){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]| 
     [2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));

```
}
?>
```

The code that refers to the checkbox is:

```
$treatment01 = $_POST['treatment01'];
```

**MY HTML code:**

```
<p><input type="checkbox" name="treatment01[]" id="checkboxG5" class="css-checkbox   
checkboxG5 treatment01" value="Back & Neck Aroma Massage" /><label for="checkboxG5" 
class="css-label">Back & Neck Aroma Massage</label></p>

<p><input type="checkbox" name="treatment01[]" id="checkboxG6" class="css-checkbox 
checkboxG6 treatment01" value="Hello" /><label for="checkboxG6" class="css-
label">Hello</label></p>
```

**and then the javascript** that does the form validation (I'm not sure if it's necessary posting this but here it is anyway):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('.checkinform').submit(function() {
    var action = $(this).attr('action');
    var form = this;
    $('.submit', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').after(
          '<img src="assets/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />');
    $('.message', this).slideUp(750, function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $.post(action, {
            title: $('.title', form).val(),
            firstname: $('.firstname', form).val(),
            lastname: $('.lastname', form).val(),
            idnum: $('.idnum', form).val(),
            birth: $('.birth', form).val(),
            married: $('.married', form).val(),
            officephone: $('.officephone', form).val(),
            cellphone: $('.cellphone', form).val(),         
            email: $('.email', form).val(),
            company: $('.company', form).val(),
            position: $('.position', form).val(),
            addressline1: $('.addressline1', form).val(),
            addressline2: $('.addressline2', form).val(),
            city: $('.city', form).val(),
            postalcode: $('.postalcode', form).val(),
            bookingdate: $('.bookingdate', form).val(),
            estimate: $('.estimate', form).val(),
            currentpackages: $('.currentpackages', form).val(),
            treatment01: $('.treatment01', form).val(),
            specialrequests: $('.specialrequests', form).val(),
            verify: $('.verify', form).val()
        },
        function(data) {
            $('.message', form).html(data);
            $('.message', form).slideDown('slow');
            $('img.loader', form).fadeOut('fast', function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
            $('.submit', form).removeAttr('disabled');
        });
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

I though checkboxes would be a walk in the park but I've spent so many hours trying to work this out to the point where I'm making guesses hoping to come right!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
name="treatment01[]"
```

Not only are you using the same name twice, you are naming it like it's an empty array, or something.  I see that you have different IDs on them.  But that doesn't matter as the NAME is what gets passed through.  So you can't check them seperately like you're trying.

Comment: Woah that was fast :) !! Ok hold on ... when I was doing research people often said that you could use the same name for name="" ?

Comment: Example - as per this website ... http://www.phpbook.net/get-checkbox-value-in-php.html ... you'll see name="language[]" has been used in all their checkbox fields

Comment: Oh and yes, the ID's are there because I have styled the checkboxes using css

Comment: @user3869603 Ah yes, sorry I wasn't looking hard enough!

Answer (score 0):

OK - since you want a more traditional submission of an array to be processed in PHP, you can do this in the `post` params

```
currentpackages: $('.currentpackages', form).val(),
treatment01: $('.treatment01:checked', form).serializeArray(),
specialrequests: $('.specialrequests', form).val(),
```

Then in your PHP

```
$selectedTreatments = '';
if(isset($_POST['treatment01'])){
    $treatments = $_POST['treatment01'];
    foreach($treatments as $treatment){
        //Here we concatenate all treatments in a string with a `<br/>` placed at the end of each one to make them break into separate lines
        $selectedTreatments .= 'Treatment selected: ' . $treatment . '<br/>';
    }
} else {
    $selectedTreatments = 'No treatments selected';
}
```

and then later on in the file change

```
<td width="375" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px;">'.$_POST['treatment01'].'</span></td>
```

To

```
<td width="375" valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:14px;">'.$selectedTreatments.'</span></td>
```

[How to send a checkbox group via ajax in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298777/how-to-send-a-checkbox-group-via-ajax-in-jquery)

Comment: Hi Rob, I think at the end of the line treatment01: $('.treatment01:checked', form).serializeArray(). there should be a comma instead of a full stop ... listen I'm very stupid when it comes to php so please bare with me. In my javascript file I replaced ... treatment01: $('.treatment01', form).val(), ... with your version ... treatment01: $('.treatment01:checked', form).serializeArray(), ... and in my php file from ... $treatment01 = $_POST['treatment01']; ... to ... $treatments = $_POST['treatment01'];
foreach($treatments as $treatment){
    $treatment01 .= $treatment['value'];
} ...

Comment: ... and now my ajax isn't working like it should though the php form does still go through but when tick the checkboxes it then arrives saying "Array" instead of the values. Just so you know my form and ajax goes through 100%

Comment: I mean all I'm asking is to just send/email a form that has checkboxes ... must I update my php form processor to include all the code?

Comment: Absolutely, was a typo, comma it should have been! Yes those are the things you should have replaced.  Not sure why you are getting array at all?  Should work according to the link I gave you.

Comment: I've included my full PHP code now ... it's a lot of coding! I absolutely hate this 4 INDENT BS!! Why can't we just wrap code in [code][/code]!

Comment: Looks like you haven't updated the PHP code to iterate through the array like I suggested and then you'll have to add each `treatment` into `msg` too for it to work.

Comment: Yes correct I added my initial complete php code incase after seeing the entire code, your answer would be different. When you say "//Do whatever here like concatenating them for your email" ... I haven't a clue what that means ... and "you'll have to add each treatment" is also a mind boggle to me what you mean?

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the update. Ok with the changes you've given me I've got the following issues: 1) When I don't select any of the checkboxes my form isn't producing the success message (although I do still receive the email - it shows correctly that none of the checkboxes were ticked) 2) When I do tick a checkbox, the form produces the success message but in the email, instead of the field giving me the value, it gives me this "Treatement selected: Array"

Comment: I cannot believe putting checkboxes into an online form is so hard and impossible to find online with the form I'm using!

Comment: So does no one know how to do checkboxes in a form?

Comment: OK - I think what must have been happening with point `1` was because we weren't checking if `$_POST['treatment01'])` was set, PHP was echoing out an error/warning which prevented your `success` message from showing.  I have added a check in the PHP code above for that eventuality.  As for it showing `Treatment selected: Array` it certainly shouldn't be doing that?
Here is a pastebin test you can have a look at http://pastebin.com/xQzbVwtR